# How to handle back button in fragments in ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to handle back button in several fragments(in ActionBarActivity) , but it didn't work.

One of fragments's onKeyDown():

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if ((!currentDir.getName().equals("sdcard")) && (currentDir.getParentFile() != null)) {
            currentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
            fill(currentDir);
             Log.v(TAG,"true." );
        } else {
            getActivity().finish();
             Log.v(TAG,"false." );
        }
        return false;
    }
    return super.getActivity().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do it and how to handle back button in other fragments in ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onKeyDown(...)` will never be called in a fragment so in order to handle the back button you have to move your code to the **ActionBarActivity**. In addition to this I would recommend you using the `onBackPressed()` method instead. That's because the onKeyDown-method will be called twice (*without further modification) if you keep the back-button pressed.

So you're final code in your ActionBarActivity would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  if ((!currentDir.getName().equals("sdcard")) && (currentDir.getParentFile() != null)) {
      currentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
      fill(currentDir);
      Log.v(TAG,"true." );
  } else {
      getActivity().finish();
      Log.v(TAG,"false." );
  }
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

### Edit

In order to call a getter-Method of your **Fragment** in your **ActionBarActivity** you can do something like this in your Activity:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane); // The id of your container
    if (currentFragment instanceof MyFragment) {
        // Cast the Fragment to your Fragment so that you can access the public method
        currentDirName = ((MyFragment) currentFragment).getCurrentDir();
    } else if (currentFragment instanceof MyOtherFragment)
        currentDirName = ((MyOtherFragment) currentFragment).getCurrentDir();
```

In your Fragment the `getCurrentDir()`-method just returns the currentDir name:

```
public String getCurrentDir(){
  return currentDir.getName();
}
```

Comment: But this will not work ,because I did not declare currentDir and fill() in ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Create a public getter method in your Fragment and call it from the ActionBarActivity

Comment: Can you please give an example for me to see it? I am new to android.
And other fragments also need to handle back button.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: See my edit. Hope this makes it a little bit clearer

Comment: OK. but _what is R.id.content_pane(I saw explained)?_ where is fill()? And I have 4 fragments.Should I use switch case? but what should be put behind "case"?

Comment: `R.id.content_pane` is the container where you put you're fragments in. So if you add a fragment your calling something like `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_pane, mFragment, MyFragment.class.getSimpleName());` right? And don't use a switch-case statements. Just do two more `else-if's`.

Comment: I need to declare currentDirName right? Can I build 4 method to put currentDirName~getCurrentDir()? Then done the method after calling method.

Comment: Yep you need to declare this and yes you need to declare a `getCurrentDir()` method in all of your fragments if needed. There are multiple ways how you can do it, you just need to know what you need from your fragments in order to handle the back-key properly and I guess that's 1) the currentDir-name and 2) the parent-File (separate getter method needed as well or just declare one for both)

Comment: I have a problem, why do I continuously press the back but only on a back directory, can not continuously go back.

Comment: I think I don't get the problem but your code should prevent the "continuously going back", doesn't it?

Comment: But I think maybe user need "continuously going back".Or just let it be "constantly go back" and then use Toast or Dialog to remind user.